# Show that $\Vert M \Vert \le 1/\lambda$ for $M = (S+\lambda I + \lambda\eta A)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

For the given matrix
$$M = (S+\lambda I + \lambda\eta A)^{-1},$$
where $S,A$ are positive definite matrix, $I$ is identity matrix, $\lambda, \eta > 0$, my goal is to show that $\Vert M \Vert \le 1/\lambda$.

I tried to use $\Vert B^{-1}\Vert \Vert B \Vert \ge 1$ and $\Vert B+C \Vert \le \Vert B \Vert + \Vert C \Vert$ , but I failed to apply them.

I'd like to check if I can obtain the desired result $\Vert M \Vert \le 1/\lambda$, and if so, what properties of operator norm I have to use.

Any help or guidance regarding this question would be grateful, thank you.

Comment: there are no further assumptions about $S, A, \eta$?

Comment: I editted some omitted conditions (not sure whether they are important for obtaining desired result).

Comment: Because $S, A \geq 0$, $\lambda, \eta > 0$, we have $S + \lambda I + \lambda\eta A \geq \lambda I$. Hence, $M = (S + \lambda I + \lambda\eta A)^{-1}$ satisfies $0 \leq M \leq 1/\lambda I$, so $||M|| \leq 1/\lambda$.

Comment: I guess $M \le (1/\lambda)I$ comes from the property $B \ge C \Leftrightarrow C^{-1} \ge B^{-1}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @jason1 Yes, that statement holds for any positive invertible operators $B$, $C$, which is the case here.